# RTE text to email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using TinyMCE in my website to get some data

I am storing the data in the MySQL database .. I am storing the HTML generated from the RTE to the database

It works fine when I have to display the data on a browser and everything is neatly formatted

However When I try to send that via email ... I get HTML in the email (and that too escaped)

Emailer code (just a start) is as follows:

```
public static void sendMail(String to, String from, String subject, String content) 
throws Exception
{
    if(!ScribeBookConstants.isEmailEnabled())
        return;

    //String host = "s155.eatj.com";
    String host = ScribeBookConstants.getEmailHost();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};

    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);

    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText(content);

    Transport.send(msg);

}
```

I tried to send an email to a Gmail account ... and get escaped HTML in the message text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the solution

I just had to set the content type to "text/html"

Answer (score 0):

Unescape content before calling setText().

Comment: acrtually ... I am not escaping the content ... I am storing it as a plain HTML without escaping